# Mostrar elementos de dos lista simples, de forma aleatoria en c++

Tags: c++, random

estoy practicando clases con listas simplemente ligadas y la funcion rand() y srand, aclaro que soy nuevo programando y hay muchas cosas que no comprendo. El problema me pide que "realice un programa que imprima una lista de 10 alumnos, con nombres aleatorios con formato "Apellido, Nombre".
esto es lo que tengo, he creado dos instancias(apellido nombre) pero lo que no puedo hacer es mostrar un nombre y un apellido de manera aleatoria. espero me puedan guiar para resolver el problema, gracias

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

struct Nodo {
     string dato;
     int pos;
     struct Nodo *siguiente;
};
typedef struct Nodo *Puntero;

class Lista{
     private:
     Puntero lista;
     Puntero lista2;
     public:
     Lista(void);
     ~Lista(void);
     void agregarPrincipio(Nodo *&, string);
     void agregarFinal(Nodo *&, string);
     void mostrar(Nodo *, int pos);
     void quitar(Nodo *&, string&, int);
};

Nodo *lista, *lista2= NULL;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int pos=0, pos2=0;

//instancia de clase
    Lista Nombre;
    Lista Apellido;
    string dato, dat1;

//carga de alumnos
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){

        cout<<"\nIngrese un nombre: ";
        cin>>dato;
        Nombre.agregarPrincipio(lista,dato);
        cout<<"\nIngrese un apellido: ";
        cin>>dat1;
        Apellido.agregarPrincipio(lista2, dat1);
    }
       //imprime las dos listas por separado
        cout<<"\nLista de nombres"<<endl;
        Nombre.mostrar(lista, pos);
        cout<<"\n";
        cout<<"\nLista de apellidos"<<endl;
        Apellido.mostrar(lista2, pos2);
        cout<<"\n\n";

        //deberia imprimir de forma aleatoria un nombre y un apellido 
        cout<<"\nNombre  y  Apellido"<<endl;

        while((lista!=NULL)&&(lista2!=NULL)){

        Nombre.quitar(lista,dato, pos),Apellido.quitar(lista2,dat1, pos2);

       if((lista!=NULL)&&(lista2!=NULL)){

        srand(time(NULL));
        pos=rand()%2;
        pos2=rand()%2;
        cout<<pos<<dato<<" , "<<pos2<<dat1<<endl;

        }

          else{
          cout<<pos<<dato<<" , "<<pos2<<dat1;
          }
        }

    return 0;
}

Lista::Lista(void){
lista = NULL;
lista2 = NULL;

}

Lista::~Lista(void){

}

void Lista::agregarPrincipio(Nodo *&lista, string x){
      Nodo *nuevo_nodo = new Nodo();
      nuevo_nodo->dato = x;
      nuevo_nodo->siguiente = lista;
      lista = nuevo_nodo;

      cout<<"\nPalabra agregada"<<endl;

}

void Lista::agregarFinal(Nodo *&lista, string x){
      Nodo *nuevo_nodo = new Nodo();
      nuevo_nodo->dato = x;

      Nodo *aux = lista;
      if(lista==NULL){
      lista = nuevo_nodo;

      cout<<"\nPalabra agregada"<<endl;
      }
      else{
        while(aux->siguiente != NULL){
            aux = aux->siguiente;
        }
        aux->siguiente = nuevo_nodo;

      cout<<"\nPalabra agregada"<<endl;
      }

 }

void Lista::mostrar(Nodo *lista, int pos){
   pos=0;
   Nodo *actual = lista;

   if(actual == NULL){
    cout<<"\nLista vacia";
   }
   else{
    while(actual != NULL){
        cout<<" ["<<pos<<"]"<<actual->dato<<"->";
        actual = actual->siguiente;
        pos++;
    }
   }

}

void Lista::quitar(Nodo *&lista, string &x, int pos){
       pos=0;
       if(lista!=NULL){

       Nodo *aux = lista;
       x = aux->dato;
       lista = aux->siguiente;
       delete aux;
       pos++;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Lo que no puedo hacer es mostrar un nombre y un apellido de manera aleatoria

En primer lugar ¿Cómo pretendes mostrar un elemento aleatorio de la lista si no tienes ninguna función que te permita acceder a una posición arbitraria de la misma? Echo en falta  una función que, dado un número, te de el elemento guardado en la posición del número facilitado:

```
class Lista{
    // ... cosas ...
    public:
    // ... cosas ...
    string elemento_en_posicion(int posicion); // <--- Te falta esto!
    int cuantos_elementos_estoy_guardando();   // <--- Y también esto!
};
```

Pero sin saber cuántos elementos tiene cada lista, no puedes saber hasta qué posición máxima puedes solicitar. Tu implementación de lista no ofrece ninguna manera de saber la cantidad de datos que contiene.

De hecho, tu implementación de lista es incorrecta a nivel de diseño y nomenclatura, además de generar fugas de memoria; todo esto en un vistazo rápido sin entrar analizar el algoritmo. Te aconsejo que **NO** reinventes la rueda y uses la lista de la librería estándar: [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list). Dado que la pregunta no es sobre cómo implementar listas, no entraré en mas detalles respecto a ello.

---

En tu código estás usando las utilidades de generación de números pseudoaleatorios de [c](/questions/tagged/c), las cuales se consideran obsoletas, ineficientes, imprecisas y poco seguras; por ello [se ha planteado deprecarlas en C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3924.pdf). En lugar de usar esas utilidades, deberías usar las utilidades de la cabecera [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random), lo que quiere decir que no necesitarás las cabeceras `<ctime>` ni `<cstdlib>`.

En tu caso, parece que una distribución aleatoria uniforme será la opción más adecuada, puedes crear una función auxiliar que te de un valor aleatorio hasta un valor máximo:

```
#include <random>

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());

int aleatorio(int maximo)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, maximo);
    return dis(gen);
}
```

Una vez tienes esa función, el obtener un nombre y apellidos aleatorios de una lista es trivial:

```
int main()
{
    Lista Nombre;
    Lista Apellido;

    // Añadir datos

    string nombre = Nombre.elemento_en_posicion(aleatorio(Nombre.cuantos_elementos_estoy_guardando() - 1));
    string apellido = Apellido.elemento_en_posicion(aleatorio(Apellido.cuantos_elementos_estoy_guardando() - 1));

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo de uso en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/i9gO7Zp51JftSh46).

Comment: hola PaperBirdMaster te agradezco por tu respuesta, desgraciadamente es asi como nos mostraron(digo mostraron por que ni siquieran nos explicaron solo nos pasaron el codigo y que nosotros experimentemos) en la universidad de como hacer una lista y a generar aleatoriamente algo, voy a intentar cambiar lo que tengo por tus correcciones,  gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Buenos días @Tommyboy , si en la universidad os están enseñando a programar así, pongo seriamente en entredicho la utilidad de esas clases. Por favor, indica las limitaciones que os imponen en el código para poder aportar alguna sugerencia diferente.

Comment: hola PaperBirdMaster, gracias por ayudar, estuve viendo lo de std::list pero creo que no tengo los conocimientos como para hacer mi proyecto. Volviendo a la enseñanza en la uni solo vemos lenguaje c y al final del año nos dieron un poco de c++(clases). Lo divertido de todo que el examen final es puro c++(clase, listas simplemente ligadas, estructuras, pilas y colas)osea siempre pide clase con alguna de las otras estructuras.Lo que pude hacer lo saque viendo videos mas lo que me guiaste, ahora estoy cambiando el codigo para que tenga en cuenta el tamaño de la lista y la posicion de los datos.